# Loading AR of big ARWorldMap file causing delay on the screen

Tags: swift, arkit, arworldmap

When the ARWorldMap file is big (20mb++), the AR in the screen becomes very lag even in iPhone 12 Pro Max that have a LIDAR camera. In the non-LIDAR, it automatically crashes. Do you have any insight on this? What should I do to optimize this issue?